# The set of limit points

Tags: analysis

$M = \{x\in\mathbb R\mid 0<x<1\}$

In any neighborhood of any point in a set there are elements of this set.

Is it true that a convergent sequence or subsequence can be distinguished in $M$?

And if $M$ is closed?

By definition, all points of the set $M$ are limit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There exist convergent sequences in $M$ that do not converge to a point in $M$. For example, $$x_n=1-\frac1n \to 1 \text{ for } n\to\infty.$$

Since $1 \notin M$, the set $M$ is not closed.

Comment: but $1$ is the limit point, even if the set is not closed

Comment: Yes, we agree on that. The fact that $1 \notin M$ makes the set not closed.